# StackOverflowError in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2, infinite-loop

I have a strange "infinite loop" in log4j2.
I found it in the tomcat catalina.out and have to idea where it comes from because there is no other packages involved the whole error stack trace.
Is this a know bug or did I configure something wrong.
The version of log4j2 I'm using is 2.17.1

```
2022-01-25 01:17:03,517 WARN org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog caught java.lang.StackOverflowError logging SimpleMessage: Application exception overridden by rollback exception java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StringBuilders.appendSpecificTypes(StringBuilders.java:79)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.appendSpecialTypes(ParameterFormatter.java:484)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.recursiveDeepToString(ParameterFormatter.java:473)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.recursiveDeepToString(ParameterFormatter.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterFormatter.formatMessage2(ParameterFormatter.java:191)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterizedMessage.formatTo(ParameterizedMessage.java:227)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterizedMessage.getFormattedMessage(ParameterizedMessage.java:203)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ParameterizedNoReferenceMessageFactory.newMessage(ParameterizedNoReferenceMessageFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.AbstractMessageFactory.newMessage(AbstractMessageFactory.java:99)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2057)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1931)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.warn(AbstractLogger.java:2805)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.handleLogMessageException(AbstractLogger.java:2225)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2208)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2058)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1931)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.warn(AbstractLogger.java:2805)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.handleLogMessageException(AbstractLogger.java:2225)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2208)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2058)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1931)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.warn(AbstractLogger.java:2805)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.handleLogMessageException(AbstractLogger.java:2225)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2208)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2058)
```

Comment: are you using Lombok's @Data on logged objects by any chance?

Comment: No I don't. Looks like that some error happens during logging "handleLogMessageException" which causes log4j2 to log the error and that runs into a loop.

Comment: can you show what is being logged?

Comment: No, I don't know who starts logging. The Stacktrace only shows the org.apache.logging.* stuff. There is no business logic or custom code shown. But shouldn't log4j2 avoid running into something like this in all cases? Even if the call from the "client" is buggy.

Comment: What appenders are you using?  Is it possible to add the log4j2.xml file in your question?

Comment: After reverting my changes backward to the point where the problem disappears I found out that the problem is caused by: 
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} [%5.5t] %5.5p %50.50c {%20.20M,%5.5L} - %m%n"/>. Here I added the fix column with to the log lines by adding 5.5 for example.